# Deploy projeto python django no heroku. Estou tendo erros

Tags: python, heroku

Estou tentando fazer deploy de um projeto Python usando Django no Heroku. O deploy ocorre tudo bem, mas ao tentar fazer heroku run python manage.py migrate ocorre o seguinte erro.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 23, in
>      execute_from_command_line(sys.argv) File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 371, in execute_from_command_line   utility.execute() File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 317, in execute   settings.INSTALLED_APPS File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 56, in **getattr**   self._setup(name) File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 43, in _setup   self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module) File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 106, in **init**   mod =
>   importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE) File
>   "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126,
>   in import_module   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:],
>   package, level) File "", line 994, in
>   _gcd_import File "", line 971, in _find_and_load File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked File "",
>   line 678, in exec_module File "", line
>   219, in _call_with_frames_removed File
>   "/app/djangosige/configs/**init**.py", line 3, in    from
>   .settings import * File "/app/djangosige/configs/settings.py", line 4,
>   in    from .configs import DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL,
>   DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD,
>   EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_USE_TLS ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'mjsolutions.configs.configs'

---

Esse é meu arquivo configs.py

---

```
# Configuração da base de dados

# Caso seja deixado vazio o default será: 'sqlite:////...djangosige/db.sqlite3'
DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://meuuser:minhasenhadbc@localhost/nomebd'

# Configurações do servidor de email

# Endereço de email padrão utilizado

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'meu@email.com'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'  # Gmail
# EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.live.com' #Hotmail

# Usuário do email padrão
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'meuuser'

# Senha do email padrão
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'minhasenha'

#Verificar a port utilizada pelo serviço de email
EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

---

Meu settings.py

```
import os
from decouple import config, Csv
from dj_database_url import parse as dburl
from .configs import DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL, DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_HOST_USER, EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD, EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_USE_TLS

APP_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(APP_ROOT))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', default=[], cast=Csv())

if not DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL:
    DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'db.sqlite3')

DATABASES = {
    'default': config('DATABASE_URL', default=DEFAULT_DATABASE_URL, cast=dburl),
}


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar com este erro? Obrigado desde já

Comment: havia um comentario (como resposta) sobre [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/382107/7412) em que vc afirmava ja criado o `requirements.txt` com o `pip freeze`, ok, mas tenha certeza de que vc esta enviando esse arquivo para o Heroku, precisa ser com esse nome: `requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Veja o final da mensagem de erro:

```
EMAIL_PORT, EMAIL_USE_TLS ModuleNotFoundError: 
      No module named 'mjsolutions.configs.configs'
```

Ou seja, voce esta chamando um módulo que, embora provavelmente esteja instalado no seu ambiente local (se não não funcionaria), não está instalado no Heroku, para funcionar no Heroku todos os pacotes necessarios para rodar em produção tem que estar no arquivo chamado `requirements.txt`, uma forma rápida de ter certeza de ter tudo nesse arquivo é com o comando:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

**Cuidado:**
Se utilizar o comando `pip freeze > requirements.txt` para gerar `requirements.txt` revise esse arquivo no final, pois localmente vc pode ter pacotes que não sejam necessários ao projeto, como por exemplo, pacotes de debug e, principalmente, se não tiver isolando os ambientes com algum tipo de gerenciador de venvs. Se for o caso, retire os pacotes desnecessarios para rodar no Heroku.

Exemplo de um arquivo `requirements.txt`:

```
$ cat requirements.txt 
Django==2.1.5
django-bootstrap4==0.0.7
django-filter==2.0.0
django-tables2==2.0.3
django-markup==1.3
tablib<0.11.99
django-markup[all-filter-dependencies]
djangorestframework==3.9.0
docutils==0.14
docopt==0.6.2
drf-tracking==1.5.0
drfdocs==0.0.11
Markdown==3.0.1
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2018.9
requests==2.21.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.24.1
whitenoise==4.1.2
yarg==0.1.9
gunicorn
```